# /etc/ folder missing on VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Apologies if Iam at wrong place to post my issue.

I've spin a CentOS VM on GCP. Some how I

```
root@mygit090820 ~]# cd ~/etc/
-bash: cd: /root/etc/: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the command line again:

```
[root@mygit090820 ~]# cd ~/etc/
-bash: cd: /root/etc/: No such file or directory
```

This command means that you, as a root in this case, want to change current directory to `/etc/` directory in your home directory `~`, which is `/root` for root. The error message you see is expected, because there's no `/root/etc/` directory. You can clearly see what's wrong in the error message.

**To solve your issue** you should run `cd /etc/` instead of `cd ~/etc/`.

In addition, please have a look at these articles [Using The Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) and [Linux System Commands](https://centoshelp.org/resources/commands/linux-system-commands/) and search for examples with `~`.